# Как добавить scrollbar к отдельной колонке DataGrid в xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gui

Есть XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"
              CanUserReorderColumns="False"
              CanUserSortColumns="False"
              HeadersVisibility="Column"
              HorizontalGridLinesBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}"
              IsReadOnly="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding FlatNodeList}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNode,
                                     Mode=TwoWay}"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              VerticalGridLinesBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}"
              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
              EnableRowVirtualization="True"
              EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
              VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
              VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True">
            <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6 2 6 2" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <DataGrid.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Key="Right" Command="{Binding ExpandThreadCommand}" />
                <KeyBinding Key="Left" Command="{Binding CollapseThreadCommand}" />
            </DataGrid.InputBindings>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="180" Header="Date">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat={StaticResource DateTimeFormat}}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="80" Header="Elapsed">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Elapsed, StringFormat={StaticResource TimeSpanFormat}}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="0.1*" Header="Data">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Margin="{Binding Margin}"
                                    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance model:NodeWrapper,
                                                                             IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"
                                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    Height="Auto">
                                    <ToggleButton ClickMode="Press"
                                                  IsChecked="{Binding Expanded,
                                                                      Mode=TwoWay,
                                                                      UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                  Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}"
                                                  Visibility="{Binding HasChildren,
                                                                       Converter={StaticResource xBoolToVisibilityConverterEx}}" />
                                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data, Mode=OneWay}">
                                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                <WrapPanel />
                                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, Mode=OneWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="{Binding TextColor}" />
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
            </DataGrid.Resources>
        </DataGrid>
```

Для колонки Data нужно сделать scrollbar горизонтальный - как это сделать?

Comment: _есть код, но его я показать не могу_, ну так вставьте туда какой-нибудь `TextBlock`, чтобы вашу разметку можно было скопировать и вставить в студию для тестирования. А вообще, есть такой контрол `ScrollViewer`, поищите примеры его использования в `DataGrid`.

Comment: Вы можете сделать воспроизводимый пример? Это поможет получить верный ответ. А неверный ответ можете удалить, потому что он только сбивает с толку.

Comment: 1) Вы можете полностью переопределить полный шаблон `DataGrid` и построить свой новый мир внутри нее, но это очень длинный xaml получится. 2) Можно засунуть в горизонтальную `StackPanel` несколько `DataGrid`, добавить скорлл туда, куда нужно. Второй способ быть может выглядит как бред, но я бы определенно его попробовал.

Comment: Второй метод доавит кучу скроллбоксов. А мне нужен один внизу и прокрутка смотря на самый выпирающий элемент в столбце Data.

Comment: Для задачи "позволяющий прочитать", если со скроллом не прокатит, есть другой прием - тултип. То есть, определить для ячейки, влезает содержимое в видимую область или нет, и если не влезает - показывать тултип с полным содержимым при наведении мыши. Я много где видел в интерфейсах подобный прием.

Comment: @aepot - не, это не прокатит

Comment: Там не просто же текст...